# Div goes outside parent Div when resloution increased after 90%

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

In my code http://codepen.io/rachidasen/pen/MwGBKe  the content of modal is going outside the modal. I don't want to widen my model . I just want that modal content div get wdth of the modal . Any help is appreciated.

```
<a href="#officer_info" style="color:green;" data-toggle="modal" id="clickprofile">OFFICER PROFILE </a>
 <div class="modal modal-wide fade" id="officer_info" >
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="min-width:70%">
        <!-- Modal content -->
        <div class="modal-content" >
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="show-profile" style="max-width:90%">
            //1st div content
            //2nd div content

            </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace `.container` class with `.container-fluid`, because you want the row to be as big as your modal pop-up.

Please check the fork http://codepen.io/halfzebra/pen/aOGjBL

Comment: thanks buddy for telling the cause why was this happening and solution

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `tab-pane` make sure you are not using the class `container`. Use `col-xs-12` instead

the container class is set to 1170px by default by bootstrap

Do this instead

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">
     <div class="col-xs-12">
      .....
     </div>
 </div>
```